# Which is the best method to display thumbnail images on UIScrollview (downloaded from server)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I want to show a number of images (as thumbnails) on the UIScrollview (like the Photos app). 
All the images will be downloaded from the server. To display, as per my knowledge, there are few alternatives:

1) By creating UIImageviews and then add them as subview on main scrollview
2) By subclassing a UIView class, and then draw images on it 
3) Using CATiledLayer class

I guess, the 1st alternative is not good enough as it is not best method, when loading large number of images; and 3rd alternate is more appropriate for large images. As I will be getting only small images, so the 2nd alternate seems best in my case.

Please suggest, for which option I should go for. If feasible, please provide sample code.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think so as there could be any number of images fetched from server. Suppose if there are 100 images fetched, I guess creating 100 UIImageViews and adding them UIScrollview is not a good idea. I think drawing images directly on a view would be good idea. Please suggest..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "[UIImageView] is not good enough as its is not optimized"? Do you really think `UIImageView` is not optimized for displaying images?

My advice: Go with the easiest solution and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Easiest solutions are not always the best solutions. I am considering speed and memory. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I released a free library made specifically for this problem: HJCache.We've used it in a number of apps, including our Facebook app Focus for Facebook. It asynchronously downloads, caches in files, shares images when repeated on screen (eg posts from from the same person with same profile thumbnail), automatically manages downloading the correct set of images in the correct order when the user scrolls through a large table of images, and is easy to use with a 'load the next image ahead' design for full screen photo browsing.

http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/

Comment: That seems impressive. Nice work. Thanks. I will explore your code more. (For a quick que: Did you use image views to display images, or you just draw them  directly on table cells?)

Comment: Both. In one app we use UIViews that contain UIImageViews. In another older app we wanted smooth scrolling on 1st generation iphone with a cell design that included rounded corners on the image and graphics and text overlayed on a graduated background. That was done using custom drawInRect code using the graphics context (which is much faster). For newer apps we do not bother doing this, as most users are on 3GS and iPhone 4, and those are plenty fast enough to scroll a complex view layout.